# Parsing Json data in JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I saw a similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289078/parse-json-from-jquery-ajax-success-data). But my returned data format is a bit different.
I have a Json string returned from server as shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>


</style>
</head>
<body>

{"error":false}</body>
</html>
```

I need to extract data `"error":false` from the Json string.
I tried as below

(1)Say the Json message is in result variable, then I checked as

```
if(result.error == false)
```

It doesn't work.

(2) I also used `jQuery.parseJSON` as discussed in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883760/parse-json-data-in-jquery).
It doesn't work also.
How can I parse Json data?

Json data is parsed in `Jquery.ajax` for the returned message as follow

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "registrationdatavalidationatserver.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("form").serialize(), /*grab all elements in your form and serialize them */
        success:  function(result){
           //To parse result

        },
        error: function(){
           // the AJAX request failed as in timed out / bad url etc.

        } 
   });
```

(3) How to return message from server just Json data without

```
<html>, <head>, <style>, etc. tags?
```

I returned from server as `echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: Wait, are you saying that the JSON along with all those HTML is being returned?

Comment: You have html before / after JSON, so it can't be parsed as you are expecting. Your response only should be like this `{"error":false}`

Answer (score 2):

> *I have a Json string returned from server as shown below.*

No, you need to have only the following returned from the server:

```
{"error": false}
```

> Say the Json message is in result variable, then I checked as `if(result.error == false)`

It will never work because it is a HTML. Not a JSON.

> *How to return message from server just Json data without* `<html>`, `<head>`

Even before you send the output, please make sure you are not sending anything to browser. Have these defined in the PHP headers:

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: application/json");
  die(json_encode($arrayData));
?>
```

There must not be anything other than this. It is wise to have a dedicated file for JSON output too, if you are confused in making this kind of setup.