# Json get data value

Tags: php, jquery, json

I need to get only id data

```
{"register":{"id":"1","members_count":null,"name":"Neha","user_name":"Neha","email":"help.eduexpression.com@gmail.com","profileId":"8866","maritialstatus_id":"1","religion_id":"1","caste_id":null,"mothertongue_id":"4","employed_id":"6","country_id":"103"}}
```

need to do jquery json decode

o/p: register.id

Comment: please describe your problem

Comment: i want to decode above json object in jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Json data in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883760/parse-json-data-in-jquery)

Comment: are you using ajax() for somthing

Answer (score 3):

```
var jsondata='{"register":{"id":"1","members_count":null,"name":"Neha","user_name":"Neha","email":"help.eduexpression.com@gmail.com","profileId":"8866","maritialstatus_id":"1","religion_id":"1","caste_id":null,"mothertongue_id":"4","employed_id":"6","country_id":"103"}}';

var result=$.parseJSON(jsondata);

// OR

var result=JSON.parse(jsondata);

console.log(result.register.id); //result will be 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
var obj ='{"register":{"id":"1","members_count":null,"name":"Neha","user_name":"Neha","email":"help.eduexpression.com@gmail.com","profileId":"8866","maritialstatus_id":"1","religion_id":"1","caste_id":null,"mothertongue_id":"4","employed_id":"6","country_id":"103"}}';

var json = JSON.parse(obj);

alert(json.register['id']);
```